Mock clickhouse-go.driver.Row.Scan(dest ...any) function to fill the first argument with mockery
I'm using mockery and i need to mock clickhouse-go.driver.Row.Scan(dest ...any) function to fill the first argument with the given data. In my case the code looks like so:
func Test_1(test *testing.T) {
     test.Parallel()
    
     ch := ch_mock.NewMockConn(test)
     row := ch_mock.NewMockRow(test)
     row.EXPECT().Scan(mock.AnythingOfType("*int64")).RunAndReturn(func(args ...any) error {
        args[0] = 1
        return nil
     })
    ch.EXPECT().QueryRow(mock.Anything, mock.Anything).Return(row)
    ...(inject the ch object into the code i'm actually testing)
}

The Scan function is used internally in the code i'm testing, and when it's called - the value of 1 isn't passed into the given argument:
var avg int64
if err := row.Scan(&avg); err != nil {
    ....
}
fmt.Println(avg) // prints 0 (the default value)

I didn't expect this to work, but it's the best i've got at the moment. I want to mock the Scan() function so it fills the first of the parameters with a provided value.
How can it be done?

This code worked for me
row.EXPECT().Scan(mock.Anything).RunAndReturn(func(args ...any) error {
        mockArgs := mock.Arguments(args)
        arg, _ := mockArgs.Get(0).(*int64)
        *arg = 1
        return nil
})

